# Best Algorithm For Merging GDS Polygons Close to Each Other

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

**background**:
I have [GDSII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDSII) layout with many rectangles all on the same layer. For those not familiar, GDSII is a file format used to store integrated circuit layouts (electronics/photonics/etc). Basically, this file format stores polygons (and metadata about what those polygons are, but ignore this). Mathematically, I have a list of rectangles on a 2D plane.

**Problem**:
I would like to merge all polygons that are close to each other. I define close as two polygons within 0.1 units of each other (units are microns but this is not relevant to the problem). Distance between two polygons is not measured center to center; instead it is the distance between the closest edges of two polygons. You can also assume that all polygons are rectangles and you can use Manhattan distance.
I am using python to process this layout. floating point can be used to represent distance.

**My Solution**:
I have a solution that is very slow (basically I am using the naive approach). I am looping through all rectangles in my list twice (nested for loop), measuring the distance between every combination of rectangles, and merging if they are close enough. This works, but is very slow and has time complexity O(n^2) and best case is also n^2 (this is not a clever algorithm).

**Question**:
If O(n^2) is the best possible, please let me know. I hope there is a solution which could provide better time complexity in the best case or maybe a smarter n^2 solution (one that is known to have small constants)?

I am using python GDSTK package, but it is fine if the solution does not use this package.
This problem mathematically is about merging rectangles on a Cartesian plane. Rectangles are stored as vertices (xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax). Rectangles can be merged by drawing a big rectangle over them or by drawing a rectangle in between them (so the two rectangles become connected basically).

Answer (score 0):

Easy algorithm:

1. Expand all rectangles by 0.1 units on the top and right sides.
2. Note all pairs of rectangles which intersect each other, using a [sweep-and-prune](https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-ii-collision-detection-for-solid-objects) algorithm.
3. Return all rectangles to their original size.
4. For each pair, if they're no longer overlapping, merge them.

Of course, that's the longhand version. The shorthand version is, do a sweep-and-prune on *implicitly* expanded rectangles and note those with 0-0.1 overlap, then merge them.

The worst-case time of this algorithm is `O(n^2)`, as any algorithm must be (because it's possible for there to be `O(n^2)` merges needed and the algorithm has to report all of them). The "normal case" runtime, however, will be `O(n log n)`. For a guaranteed `O(k + n log n)` algorithm for `k` merges, you'd use a BSP or quadtree instead of sweep-and-prune, but those are more complicated to implement, and slower in the normal case.